# Understanding Object Imports in Scala

Tags: scala

As per the accepted answer in thread [Using implicit objects within classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521938/using-implicit-objects-within-classes)

if implicit objects are encapsulated within companion object of a generic type then there is no need to explicitly import properties and behaviour from object.

With that logic I am not able to understand why is below code not getting compiled after removing import num._

```
implicit class GenericMedian[T: Numeric](seq: Seq[T]) {
    def median(): Double = {
      val num: Numeric[T] = implicitly[Numeric[T]]

      import num._
      val medianPosition = seq.length / 2
      seq.sortWith(gt) match {
        case x if x.length % 2 != 0 => x(medianPosition).toDouble()
        case x => (x(medianPosition).toDouble() + x(medianPosition - 1).toDouble()) / 2
      }

    }
  }
```

Can someone throw some light on this concept?

Answer (score 1):

Because uses of `gt` and `toDouble` that are imported from the `num` are not in the implicit position - i.e. `toDouble` is used explicitly and `sortWith` argument is not marked as implicit - so implicit resolution will not work for them.

So, the `import num._` basically puts into *explicit* scope methods used later, specifically `num.gt` and another implicit `Numeric[T].Ops` which has `toDouble` implementation.

Consider the following example - `median` is rewritten to replace those two explicit uses with calls to functions that use implicit resolution:

```
implicit class GenericMedian[T: Numeric](seq: Seq[T]) {
  def median(): Double = {
    val medianPosition = seq.length / 2
    sortWithImpl(seq) match {
      case x if x.length % 2 != 0 => makeDouble(x(medianPosition))
      case x => (
        makeDouble(x(medianPosition)) +
        makeDouble(x(medianPosition - 1))
      ) / 2
    }

  }
  private def makeDouble(t: T)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): Double = numeric.toDouble(t)

  private def sortWithImplicit(seq: Seq[T])(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): Seq[T] = seq.sortWith(numeric.gt)
}
```

Note that no `numeric` instance is conjured from implicit scope `makeDouble` and `sortWithImplicit` use implicit resolution.

For deeper understanding, consider consulting with [scala docs on implicits](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3859512/882918) (in particular, "Accessing an Implicit Parameter Introduced by a Context Bound" section)